# psycopg2: how to update multidimensional array with row

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, psycopg2

I'm struggling to update multidimensional arrays in my postgres table with new rows. In psql:

```
CREATE TABLE list_of_arrays (my_array int[]);
INSERT INTO list_of_arrays VALUES ('{{1, 2}}');
UPDATE list_of_arrays SET my_array = my_array || '{{3, 4}}';
SELECT * FROM list_of_arrays;
```

yields the array:

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

In psycopg2, however the update step fails:

```
row1 = [[1, 2]]
row2 = [[3, 4]]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO list_of_arrays VALUES (%s);", (row1,))
cur.execute("UPDATE TABLE list_of_arrays SET my_array = my_array || %s;",(row2,))
```

returns:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "TABLE" LINE 1:
UPDATE TABLE list_of_arrays SET my_array = my_array || ARRAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be like this:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE list_of_arrays SET my_array = my_array || %s;",(row2,))
```

without a keyword `TABLE`